# How to handle clicks on nested elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am given a task of making 7 nested div's such that the clicked div should change its colour to white, while all the upper div's of clicked div should change their colour to orange. While all the lower div's should change their colour to green.

```js
$(".div").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": "white"
  });
  $(this).parents().css({
    "background-color": "orange"
  });
  $(this).children().css({
    "background-color": "green"
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    div {
      border: 2px solid black;
      margin: 30px 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="div" id="1">
      <div class="div" id="2">
        <div class="div" id="3">
          <div class="div" id="4">
            <div class="div" id="5">
              <div class="div" id="6">
                <div class="div" id="7">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anant Kumar Singh only clicked div should change its colur to white and upper div's of clicked div should change colour to orange & lower div's of clicked div should change its color to green.

Comment: change `$(".div").click(function() {` to `$(".div").click(function(e) {` , to capture click event. And then add `e.stopPropagation();` to stop bubbling effect of event.explanation given in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close, actually! The reason for the boring and non-interactive output is due to how events are bubbled through elements. Here's a great article on [mdn about events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), but the most important bit is around stopping the propagation.

> The standard Event object has a function available on it called stopPropagation() which, when invoked on a handler's event object, makes it so that first handler is run but the event doesn't bubble any further up the chain, so no more handlers will be run.

So in your example, the original div might be clicked, but the other divs also receive the click and will run their code. Try adding a `event.stopPropagation()` and seeing how it changes.

P.S. You'll need to get the `event` object in your `click` handler :)

P.P.S. I believe starting to use more `console.log` and sooner-rather-than-later familiarizing yourself with debugging tools will help you immensely. In this case adding a `console.log` statement in the `click` handler, for example, would have had you asking the question, "why does my click trigger on multiple elements?"

Comment: @Namaskar but what if I click a different div second time. I don't want the previous output in my new output ?

Comment: @YashRaval good question. I will again recommend logging things. I would start by `console.log(this)` and seeing what element it is, when clicked. Then also log all of the parents `$(this).parents()`, then log all of the children `$(this).children()` and see what's going on. Look at the jQuery documentation, and other example usage. e.g. search on your favourite search engine, "jquery children` and see what it does, etc. Good luck :)